# learning php what does this means in php

Tags: php

sorry guys i am learning php, sometimes i see on tutorials people use `->` i been wondering what does this means in php ?

for example like this i saw on many tutorials

```
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    // code here ...
}
```

see simple code above has `$resultSet->num_rows` what does this means `->` and what is another way to make this code right so i can understand this ?

i am learning php and wanted to ask only what does this means and if there's any other ways instead of using `->`

Comment: $google->isYourFriend;

Comment: it points to a parameter/method of an object or class. So $resultSet here is an object or instance of a class, and `num_rows` is a property of that object.

Comment: @Jeff i don't get it jeff. because we can use this for example `mysqli_query("");` but some people use it like this `mysqli->query("");`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg if i am not wrong, it means `=` "equal" and in same time it means `_` "underscore" ?

Comment: these are 2 different ways of using the `mysqli_` extension. RTFM and it will explain [TFM page in question](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

Comment: Just lookup how to handle objects in PHP and you will find the answer.